# read tiff image tesseract and leptonica

Tags: c++, tesseract, leptonica

I want to read tiff file. And I save txt each .png files which is in tiff file. If I use below code, I cannot save each page with its name. How can I do ? (Cpp code)

```
// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract-3.02/phototest.tif");
api->SetImage(image);
// Get OCR result
char *outText;
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your code looks like this basic example: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample

Comment: This code get all ocr result, But I want to get different text per page

Comment: I want to like this :    Page 1 text : --------------------------------Page 2 Text : -------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Leptonica API](http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/) there is a special function `pixReadTiff` which reads a certain page from your tif file as Pix.

```
PIX *pixReadTiff(const char  *filename, l_int32 n)
```

It returns `NULL` or an error if the page does not exists.
Just iterate through all pages.

To get the number of pages, you can use this function:

```
 l_int32 tiffGetCount(FILE *fp, l_int32  *pn)
```

For other details you might want to look into the API yourself.
You might look into this: http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/tiffio_8c_source.html

Comment: ok. pixReadTiff(filename, page_number) , how can I know page_number ?